# ggMarginal ignores choord_cartesian. How to change marginal scales?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to plot a 2D density plot with ggplot, with added marginal histograms. Problem is that the polygon rendering is stupid and needs to be given extra padding to render values outside your axis limits (e.g. in this case I set limits between 0 and 1, because values outside this range have no physical meaning). I still want the density estimate though, because often it's much cleaner than a blocky 2D heatmap.

Is there a way around this problem, besides scrapping ggMarginal entirely and spending another 50 lines of code trying to align histograms?

**Unsightly lines:**

[image]

**Now rendering works, but ggMarginal ignores `choord_cartesian()`, which demolishes the plot:**

[image]
Data here:
http://pasted.co/b581605a

```
dataset <- read.csv("~/Desktop/dataset.csv")

library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)
library(ggExtra)
plot_center <- ggplot(data = dataset, aes(x = E,
                                          y = S)) +
    stat_density2d(aes(fill=..level..),
                   bins= 8, 
                   geom="polygon",
                   col = "black",
                   alpha = 0.5) + 
    scale_fill_continuous(low = "yellow",
                          high = "red") +
    scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-1,2)) + # Render padding for polygon
    scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-1,2)) + #
    coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 1),
                    xlim = c(0, 1)) +
    theme_tufte(base_size = 15, base_family = "Roboto") +
    theme(axis.text    = element_text(color = "black"),
          panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", fill=NA, size=1),
          legend.text  = element_text(size = 12, family = "Roboto"),
          legend.title = element_blank(),
          legend.position = "none")

ggMarginal(plot_center,
           type = "histogram",
           col = "black",
           fill = "orange",
           margins = "both")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this problem by using `xlim()` and `ylim()` instead of `coord_cartesian`.

```
dataset <- read.csv("~/Desktop/dataset.csv")

library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)
library(ggExtra)

plot_center <- ggplot(data = dataset, aes(x = E,
                                          y = S)) +
    stat_density2d(aes(fill=..level..),
                   bins= 8, 
                   geom="polygon",
                   col = "black",
                   alpha = 0.5) + 
    scale_fill_continuous(low = "yellow",
                          high = "red") +
    scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-1,2)) + # Render padding for polygon
    scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-1,2)) + #
    xlim(c(0,1)) +
    ylim(c(0,1)) +
    theme_tufte(base_size = 15, base_family = "Roboto") +
    theme(axis.text    = element_text(color = "black"),
          panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", fill=NA, size=1),
          legend.text  = element_text(size = 12, family = "Roboto"),
          legend.title = element_blank(),
          legend.position = "none")

ggMarginal(plot_center,
           type = "histogram",
           col = "black",
           fill = "orange",
           margins = "both")
```